# Flutter App cannot install from Play Store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-services

Flutter App cannot install from Play Store to some devices. Why is that?

**flutter doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale en-LK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            versionCode 135
            versionName "1.8.39"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "app""
            applicationId "..."
            versionCode 90
            versionName "1.8.31"
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar"
    implementation("com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2")
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="...">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="..."/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="@string/dynamic_link"
                    android:pathPrefix="/sp"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="@string/af_onelink_host"
                    android:pathPrefix="@string/af_onelink_prefix" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you clear cache memory of PlayStore and try again to download it

Comment: This is happening to end-users. three customers complain to us. we cannot say that.

Comment: Are they android 12?

Comment: yes. but I have already upgraded my target version to 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to update your AndroidManifest.xml for android 12 devices, [reference](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported):

> If your app targets Android 12 or higher and contains activities, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters, you must explicitly declare the android:exported attribute for these app components.

You need to addd android:exported to true