# Older version Flutter apps are not installed on new version phone from playstore

Tags: android, flutter, version, mobile-application

Apps that are built in the previous version of Flutter (version 1) are not installed in the new version of Android phones (version 12). What's the solution to this problem?

Comment: Like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897658/flutter-app-not-installable-from-google-store-for-android-12-despite-being-set-t    or like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70831283/flutter-app-cannot-install-from-play-store